# Use Local Storage to pass link ids in Chrome Web App

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a Chrome Web Store App for a local glazing company, the objective to pull in leads for their services from various social accounts and their website, I am building the JavaScript for it which currently collects the ids from a clicked linked (whether its Facebook, Twitter, Website etc) and have got it successfully to add them to local storage for now. I want to be able to recorde the ids (Facebook, Twitter etc), which the function saveBookmarks() does, and if they proceed and make an inquiry, be able to determine where that inquiry came from. This is because I am only getting paid on commission from any successful sales which came from any of the links in the app!. So I need a way to be able to pass the id information on if they make an inquiry via the various accounts that they proceed to, keeping it persistent. All the links have separate ids with a key of "ChromeApp". So it's working at present but extra clicks on the same link are recorded and added so I need a way to identify if the id value has already been added. Also as above, I would like a way to pass on the id if a user makes an inquiry via any of their accounts, their website, for example, uses an email form, and the others are all Social Media accounts, so they know it has come from the Chrome App. (Going to remove YouTube and replace with something else) I also have 2 test functions running, one which console logs all the entries as they are being added and another which deletes ids which are there (fetchBookmarks(), deleteBookmark()) but still need to find a way of not adding the id if it is already there. The deleteBookmark() function doesn't work as saveBookmarks() just keeps adding the id items. What I've got so far is below.

HTML code

```
<div class="modal-icons">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex" id="Website" onclick="saveBookmark(this.id)">
            <a href="http://allweatherroofline.com" target="_blank">
            </a>
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="flex" id="YouTube" onclick="saveBookmark(this.id)">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
            </a>
            <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="flex" id="Facebook" onclick="saveBookmark(this.id)">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
            </a>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="flex" id="Twitter" onclick="saveBookmark(this.id)">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
            </a>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="flex" id="Linkedin" onclick="saveBookmark(this.id)">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
            </a>
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    function saveBookmark(id) {
     if(localStorage.getItem('ChromeApp') === null){
    // Init array
    var linkVisit = []
    // Add to array
    linkVisit.push(id);
    // Set to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('ChromeApp', JSON.stringify(linkVisit));
  } else {
    // Get bookmarks from localStorage
    var linkVisit = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ChromeApp'));
    // Add bookmark to array
    linkVisit.push(id);
    // Re-set back to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('ChromeApp', JSON.stringify(linkVisit));
  }
fetchBookmarks();
deleteBookmark();
}
// Fetch bookmarks to test additions
function fetchBookmarks(){
  // Get bookmarks from localStorage
var linkVisit = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ChromeApp'));
console.log(linkVisit);
} 
   //Try to delete ids which are already been clicked. Doesnt work!
    function deleteBookmark(id){
  // Get bookmarks from localStorage
  var linkVisit = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ChromeApp'));
  // Loop through the bookmarks
  for(var i =0;i < linkVisit.length;i++){
    if(linkVisit[i].id == id){
      // Remove from array
      linkVisit.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
}
```

The `id` of "Twitter" "Facebook" or whatever as set, is all that is needed, but they may make multiple inquiries to different SM accounts in the same visit, and a record of all visits is needed.

Any tips are welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `.contains()` on the array.

```
function saveBookmark(id) {
     if(localStorage.getItem('ChromeApp') === null){
    // Init array
    var linkVisit = []
    // Add to array
    linkVisit.push(id);
    // Set to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('ChromeApp', JSON.stringify(linkVisit));
  } else {
    // Get bookmarks from localStorage
    var linkVisit = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ChromeApp'));
    // Add bookmark to array
    //If id is already in there, don't do anything.
    if(!linkVisit.contains(id)){
      linkVisit.push(id);
      // Re-set back to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('ChromeApp', JSON.stringify(linkVisit));
    }
  }
```

Though, I would recommend you to rework your entire code and use objects instead. Also, make your code more efficient, like so;

```
//Get the local storage item, if null, set empty object
var linkVisit = localStorage.getItem('ChromeApp') === null ? {} : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ChromeApp'));

  //Function to avoid repeated code, saves management time.
  function updateLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.setItem('ChromeApp', JSON.stringify(linkVisit));
  }

  function saveBookmark(id) {
    //Check if ID was already in the localstorage
    //If not, add it.
    if(!linkVisit.hasOwnProperty(id)){
      linkVisit[id] = id;
    }
    //Update the local storage
    updateLocalStorage();
  }

  //This function is kind of redundant now.
  function fetchBookmark(){
    console.log(linkVisit);
  }

  function deleteBookmark(id){
    //Delete the object property
    delete linkVisit[id];
    //Update local storage again
    updateLocalStorage();
  }
```

Comment: Great, 2nd way looks a lot better, just using the first 2 functions, seems to work (no repeated items) but changes the key to the id ie, instead of "ChromeApp" the key is "Facebook" and the value is Facebook. Is that OK? Not using deleteBookmark() as there is no need to delete them. Just record an id when user clicks on an item.Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. ChromeApp is they name of the localstorage item.. Even in your code. I'm not entirely sure what it is you'd like to do differently?

Comment: Thats right, but I just used the first 2 functions (2nd way) and I get, for example a key of "Facebook" and a value of Facebook, previously I was getting a key of "ChromeApp" so maybe something was wrong. Dont need to do anything differently and had too much code. Just registers the clicked id which is fine. Only used the first 2 functions verbatim. Does the job, but now need to find out how to pass on ids when users go to Facebook etc. Thanks

Comment: Whelp, I just put the value of `id` in there because I wasn't sure what you wanted there. You can do anything with it though, you know? If the key is `facebook` you could give it any value. Even another `array` or `object`. You could put anything in it you want :)

Comment: Just wanted to keep a record of the id, nothing fancy (that WOULD be beyond my scope!) so we know where subsequent inquiries came from, ie the Facebook link on their Chrome Store app) cos that's the only way I might get paid!, on any sales that come from the app. The difficulty is passing them to/via the company's social accounts as they all have different APIs which I haven't used before. Then there's also their email form on their actual website! Thanks for the help though, it sorted that bit out.